# get value from custom UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell that has a UISegmentedControl object. My UITableView (questionnaire form) has 6 of this custom cell (6 segmented controls). I am having trouble getting the `selectedSegmentIndex` of the segment controls. My guess is that the cells are being released after the table is generated. I am getting the values using the following code:

```
MyCustomCell *q1 = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:0]];

int segmentIndex = (int) q1.segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex;
```

the `int segmentIndex` is always giving the same value of `0` no matter what the selected index is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use the right method to initialize your index path for the section and row you want use, otherwise `row` and `section` properties won't be correctly set, and you will get the same cell each time :
`+(NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRow:(NSUInteger)row inSection:(NSUInteger)section;`.

The code looks like :

```
// getting the cell at third row of first section
NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];
MyCustomCell *q1 = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];
int segmentIndex = (int) q1.segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex;
```

You could also consult : [NSIndexPath UIKit Additions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Comment: I used `indexPathForRow:inSection` at first but it didn't work for some reason.