# how to access these text fields within a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a screen and a UITableView within it to display some companies information. Every company's area has 1 address text field and an arrow icon followed on UI. Click the arrow icon, contacts of this company will be showed. The data includes name and telephone. These contacts are UITableViewCells as well, which belong to same section. For 2nd company, there is another section.

In every section, below these contacts cell, there is a "Edit/Save" button. user can edit or save contacts' name and telephone by clicking it.

my question is,

I can know which Edit/Save button is clicked by using (id)sender in action method, but how can I read the values of the updated contacts' name/telephone in those 2 text fields just above the button?

Thanks in advance!

the whole table view looks like this,

company1

address     [arrow button]

contact's name
contact's telephone
[edit/save]

company2

address     [arrow button]
...

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818806/get-value-from-custom-uitableviewcell

Comment: oh, thank you very much! I checked the answer there, and I think it can solve my question well. so this question is a duplicate.

Comment: actually no need to access it by reading index. please see comments in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller should be the delegate for each `UITextField` that is used for entering details.

Whenever any text is changed, record it straight away (into a temporary store like a dictionary, using `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`). You do it immediately so you don't need to worry about completing edits at the end and so that nothing is lost if the table view is scrolled.

If the table view is scrolled and the cells are recreated you can fill in the previously entered value from the temporary store.

Now, when the save button is pressed you use the temporary store of data.

Comment: sorry my poor English possibly misleads you. In the question, I want to ask how to access these text fields by some kinds of index or whatever else. not the value itself. Now I am using your method, saving values into a temp dictionary. Sorry about my misleading question. Anyway, I just found the answer in question comment. Your answer do help too. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to access the text field when the button is pressed?

Comment: I need to update contact information to database after edit/save button is clicked. every section has this button. so I want to find which contacts are updated.

Comment: So you can have a temp store of changes for each section. You shouldn't need to go to the text fields as you would already have a record of the changes that have been made.

Comment: Yes I finally solve this by using text field delegate method. no need to access textfield index, just within delegate method, get text and save to temp store. when click the button, save the temp store to db is ok. Previously I didn't fully understand your way. Now I will accept your answer. Thanks!